# Can different Chromobactierum strains have completley different colony morphology?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

In the analysis of an unknown bacterial broth I observed a gram negative rod genus. Upon plating I observed small, dark purple and convex colonies; corresponding presumably to Chromobactierum. After then replating the purple colonies I then observed white fillamentous colonies that were gram negative and was subsequently able to make an identification that suggested the organism was either of genus aeromonas, vibrio or Chromobactierum. I found an article showing that Chromobactierum colonies dont have to be purple and can have a range of morphologies (see link). My question is: upon replating, can the morphology of the two colonies change so drastically?( assuming I had two different strains of Chromobacterium present)

Source:http://jb.asm.org/content/66/4/470.full.pdf

Comment: This different Gram reaction suggests you have a contaminant.

Comment: Sorry error on my part. The purple bacteria observed on the first plate were gram negative

Comment: It is not uncommon for bacteria to stop producing pigments when cultivated on artificial media in the lab.

Comment: Did you PCR the 16S?? Most phyla are Gram negative and several skin flora bacteria are negative and unpigmented —yes, there will be many bright yellow staphs (+) and red Serratia marcensis (-), but not all. So I agree with the contamination hypothesis.